# Validate DataGrid Cells on Load

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I am playing with the the following WPF documentation example: [How to: Implement Validation with the DataGrid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control)

The example works fine once assembled; however, there is one pitfall. The validation technique does not check for valid values on load. I have a scenario where checking the initial loaded values against db is needed.The Validate function in the example is not called until the user interacts with the view. How to overcome this challenge?

```
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        Course course = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as Course;
        // Some condition
    }
```

Comment: Validation in this case is attached to the binding between the view model and the view.  In this scenario you need to move values from the view to the view model in order to trigger validation.  What you want, I think is validation between the model and the view model which is an entirely different kettle of fish.  There is no way to suggest a solution without knowing more about how you view model is built.  Is it a DataSet for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` that you use as the `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid` should implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. Then it is only a matter of returning the errors from the `GetErrors` method.

Here is a basic example.

**Model:**

```
public class Company : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Company()
    {
        //validate immediately:
        ValidateName();
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            ValidateName();
        }
    }

    public void ValidateName()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
            _validationErrors["Name"] = "cannot be empty...";
        else
            _validationErrors.Remove("Name");
        RaiseErrorsChanged("Name");
    }


    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
    private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || !_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            return null;

        return new List<string>(1) { _validationErrors[propertyName] };
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return _validationErrors.Count > 0; }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can read more about the interface and how data validation in WPF works in general here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/